# How to update Node.js + Nginx site

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a Node.js back end up and running serving my site through Nginx. When I update the files it doesn't reflect on the actual live site.

How do I go about updating the site, preferably with no downtime but I would also like to know the easiest way with a brief bit of downtime.

Comment: There is a strong likelyhood this is because of your cache parameters. Try Ctrl+Shift+R on the web page to force-reload the cache, if that works you'll need to change your cache parameters in nginx and/or express.

Comment: Are you restart node app after upgrate their code? For production env I'm recommend `Pushion Passenger`